# Minimum Guaranteed Constant Folding in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, constant-expression, constantfolding

## Question

I am curious if there is any guarantees about constant folding being done in C.

## Where I've looked

[This link](http://www.compileroptimizations.com/category/constant_folding.htm) on a site whose reputability is unknown to me makes an offhand comment:

> All C compilers can fold integer constant expressions that are present after macro expansion (ANSI C requirement).

But I don't see anything in e.g. The C Programming Language, second edition (which I presume was thoroughly updated to account for all details of ANSI C). But after checking the index for references to relevant words, I found nothing that promises this. Pages 38 and 209 in particular come close, because they say any expression which *could* be evaluated at compile-time may be used where a constant could be used (perhaps with some restrictions, if we are pedantic enough), and it says that such expressions "**may**" be evaluated at compile-time, not "will"/(some synonym).

I searched [this C89 final draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt). The word "folding" and "folded" yielded no results of value, and the search "constant expression" generated 63 matches, of which I checked about half. The primary part of interest seems to basically be the same as the book (it uses the word "**can**" instead of "may", but those are synonymous in this context).

Both of these seem to logically strongly imply to me that every ANSI C compiler must have basic constant-folding capabilities, but at the same time, there doesn't seem to be any hard prohibition against constant expressions being compiled into code which computes the expression at runtime (such an implementation still benefits from constant expressions because the compiler can generate code which compute it once and then assumes the value won't change, and such an implementation might be forced by limitations in a given underlying architecture - e.g. several RISC architectures must either use two instructions to initialize certain possible values, or load them from a memory location).

I also briefly searched [this C99 final draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.txt), but "folding" yielded one result of no value, while "folded" and "constant" had over a hundred matches each that I currently couldn't allocate the time to crawl through.

## Motivation

I wrote these macros for more semantic/intent clarity in some bit-twiddling code:

```
#define UCHAR_LOW_N_BITS_m(n) (unsigned char )(UCHAR_MAX >> (CHAR_BIT - (n)))
#define UCHAR_NTH_BIT_m(n) (unsigned char )(1 << (n))
```

..where `n` is always an integer literal. I want to be soothed, to hear a reassuring voice say "it's okay, every C compiler in use that remotely matters will fold these constants for you". (P.S. I asked a separate question about to whether `UCHAR_NTH_BIT_m` should act as if [bits start from the 0th or 1st bit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315117/least-significant-lowest-bit-0th-or-1st-zero-or-one-indexed), hopefully in the right place.)

And yes, the bottom one could be turned into separate macros, e.g. `#define UCHAR_1ST_BIT_m (unsigned char )1` through `#define UCHAR_3RD_BIT_m (unsigned char )4` or however many I happen to need in the code - and while I'm undecided as to which of those is better, it's probably a moot point, because if I want to be a good pedantic-language-lawyer-type C programmer, I can't exactly avoid the top one (gotta make sure the code does the right thing on those DSP/embedded and ancient-mainframe C implementations).

Comment: It is up to the compiler developer. "Can" is american for "may" and means that you are allowed to but you don't have to do it. And yes, any good compiler will do it.

Comment: I don't think that usage of "can" is limited to American English.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: I appreciate the clarification, but I was aware: that's why I said "seems to basically be the same" - because I understood that although there was a wording difference, it meant essentially the same thing. I'll edit it to reduce the chance for further misunderstanding.

Comment: So, you use an all-caps symbol (a clear sign in C that this is a macro or preprocessor symbol), with a lowercase `_m` suffix to say that the symbol is a macro? Okay.

Comment: "The C Programming Language, second edition (which I presume was thoroughly updated to account for all details of ANSI C)"  It was not. The 2nd update for compatibility with C90 was half-hearted. And of course the C90 standard is obsolete since long anyhow.

Comment: @mtraceur *I want to be soothed, to hear a reassuring voice say "it's okay, every C compiler in use that remotely matters will fold these constants for you"* You will find reassurance if you look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @2501: Done that, but while my recent-ish `gcc` instances produce reassuring assembly: they are generally comforting compilers, making many optimizations which were not done by older versions of compilers which some poor soul might still be stuck using.

Comment: @unwind: So, you wanna make snide remarks regarding stylistic choices? Okay. I hope the smug satisfaction you felt when making that comment to obliquely express your judgmental attitude makes the world better in some meaningful, substantial way.

I like the suffix `_m`, especially for function-like macros. I have less fondness for all-caps symbols, but I use them for preprocessor-defined constants sometimes. The examples given are a historical artifact: they started as several plain preprocessor macros (just all-caps), then I changed them into function-like macros which took an `n` argument.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks for the clarification. The part about it being a half-hearted update is good to know. As for the obsolete nature of C89/C90, I really wish that translated to practical reality. But as recently as ~2011 or so `gcc` was defaulting to C89 with GNU extensions, Visual C Studio still doesn't support some C99 features last I heard, and I know there's a bunch of systems out there stuck on older compilers. So I think there's value to keeping C89 in mind.

Comment: @mtraceur I'm sorry if I sounded too snide. I should have expressed my amazement over this style less aggressively.

Comment: @mtraceur GCC simply forces you to explicitly tell it to behave, is all. Just do `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` and it turns into a strict C standard compiler. And since GCC 5.x.x I think it defaults to gnu11, which is C11 + extensions. As for Visual Studio, it is simply a piece of crap.

Comment: @unwind: Ah, I understand your meaning now. Thank you. To be honest, even with my initial interpretation, I got value out of your comment: it made me work to remember _why_ I had decided to have that be all-caps, `_m` excluded, and it reminded me to do another pass at evaluating the flaws and merits of my rather idiosyncratic naming habits.

Comment: @Lundin: I think you and I feel the same way about the merits of using new language standards. I agree that Visual C Studio should be rightly deprecated for not supporting C11, let alone C99, fully. But in my personal projects, I write code with the hope that it's useful/helpful for others: so I keep the people using "inferior" compilers in mind. Also, when asking questions about specification/standard details, like this question, I think there is value in being aware if a given wording was only added in a newer version of the spec, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the C standard, the term for compile-time is *translation time*, and events that happen at compile-time may be described as *during translation*. You can search the standard for those terms.

The closest thing in this standard to your topic is the definition of *constant expression* in section 6.6 (C11). The overview is:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

Note that "can be" does not mean "must be". We would expect a good quality compiler to evaluate constant expressions at compile-time although this is not an absolute requirement.

Section 6.6 is too big to paste the whole thing here, but by consulting the C Standard (or a draft such as N1570) you can read about which expressions are defined as *constant expressions* and it would be reasonable to assume that your compiler evaluates them at compile-time.

If `n >= 0 && n < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1`, and `n` is an integer constant expression, then `(unsigned char )(1 << (n))` is an *integer constant expression* because: its operands are integer constants, it doesn't use one of the operators which are forbidden in constant expressions (e.g. `++`), and the cast is allowed because it casts from integer type to another integer type.

If `n` is outside this range then the expression is not a constant expression, and causes undefined behaviour.

Your other expression is similar; it is an ICE so long as `CHAR_BIT - n` falls in that same valid range.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the C standard does not specify how something is compiled. You won't ever get a guarantee that one way to implement something is faster than another. There is no guarantee that constant folding must occur, but as the compiler must be able to evaluate constant expressions at compile time (to process `#if` directives and array declarators), it is very likely that the compiler does constant folding. After all, it makes no sense to be able to do constant folding but then not doing it.

Comment: That's more or less what I was thinking. I've +1'ed this, and I'll accept it in a day or two unless a better answer appears.

Comment: The contents of `#if` directives are evaluated by the preprocessor, not the compiler, but constant expressions are allowed within array declarations which are handled by the compiler.

Comment: @supercat The standard does not say how the compiler is implemented, it merely specifies a series of translation phases of which the first few are commonly implemented in the preprocessor.